# Enabling only one button to execute at a time from multiple buttons in android

Tags: android, button, click, onclicklistener

I have a list of image buttons which when clicked each plays a song. The problem is that I can click a button continuously thus enabling the same music to play for each button clicked.

I can also  click a different button in the `switch()` case method while the music of the other button is still playing.

How can i disable the working of multiple click when one one is in execution? Please see my code for reference.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.imageButton1:

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    sound1=MediaPlayer.create(Learn_Emela.this, R.raw.song2);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Tingg..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    sound1.start();
       break;

    case R.id.imageButton2:
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        sound1=MediaPlayer.create(Learn_Emela.this, R.raw.song2);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Tingg..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        sound1.start();
        break;
    case R.id.imageButton3:

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        sound1=MediaPlayer.create(Learn_Emela.this, R.raw.song3);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Tingg..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        sound1.start();


        break;`
```

Comment: put conditions.. if song is already playing..don't play again/new song

Comment: Not sure how you can do that. Any idea how i can use  button.setEnabled(false) method??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ckeck whether music is still running

```
    AudioManager manager = (AudioManager)this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    if(manager.isMusicActive())
     {
       // stop music
       sound1.stop();
    enableBUtton(your button1);
     enableBUtton(your button2);//likewise you can do or you can also reduce your code by other logic
     }
else{
    //start other music
    sound1.start();
}


 void enableButton(Button b){
    b.setEnable(false);
    }
```

Comment: Do i just need to paste the code as a global function at the beginning??

Comment: Yeah multiple click execution is disabled but only in each respective case. I can still play another music at the same time from another button of another case. Any more help?

Comment: can you tell me exactly what you want to do.sorry for askin again as i understood i hv updated my code..u can disable other buttons by passing button.setEnabled(false) inside if()

Comment: Thank you Sania. The word 'button' in button.setEnabled(false) is only for one particular button right? You see from the code i've shared there are so many buttons and i am able to use many buttons at the same time and i dont want that. By the way how can i declare or initialize setEnabled(false). Please help. Im just clueless!!

Comment: I clicked so many times but StackOverflow wont allow me too. :D I need atleast 15 reputations, and this is my first. :( I'll remember this and when i reach the requirement i'll give it, for sure. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

To Disable multiple clicks do this :-

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(FunActivity.this,
                        R.raw.YOUR_SONG_NAME);
                mp.start();
                BUTTON.setEnabled(false);

                Timer buttonTimer = new Timer();
                buttonTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                BUTTON.setEnabled(true);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }, 6000); //6000 is the duration of your song in seconds.
```

Hence you can disable the button for the duration for which the song is playing.